# Code to rearrange an html table in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

How could I go from this :

```
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td><input for A></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td><input for B></td>
</tr>
```

to this:

```
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input for A></td>
    <td><input for B></td>
</tr>
```

I need to move the rows into n (this changes based on the number of rows retrieved from a data set, in this case for 2 columns but it can be any number) number of columns. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could read in the table data into a two-dimensional array and then just overwrite the table data with the transposed matrix.

```
function reArrange() {
    var table = $('table#theTable');
    // we will store all the table-data in a two-dim array:
    var data = new Array();
    // find all rows (row-index: i):
    $(table).find('tr').each(function(i, row) {
        // find all cells in this row (col-index: j):
        $(row).find('td').each(function(j, cell) {
            // make sure, we got the array right:
            if ( data[j] === undefined ) {
                data[j] = new Array();
            }
            // use col-index as first index in the array:
            data[j][i] = $(cell).html();
        });
    });
    // reset table:
    $(table).find('tr').remove();  
    // re-fill table
    $(data).each(function(i, elem){
        var row = $('<tr/>');
        $(elem).each(function(j, col) {
            cell = $('<td/>').html(col);
            $(row).append(cell);
        });
        $(table).append(row);
    });

}
reArrange();
```

Have a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66YpC/2/

I hope, this is what you were looking for. If you need some more information on the code, let me know!

Comment: This moves into 3 columns but what if i need it to be in 2 columns?

Comment: Should work fine with any number of columns and rows. Give it a try. Just modify the HTML markup in the jsFiddle and click Run.